# Intersection/Union of collection of sets with the empty set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be any set and let $S$ be any collection of subsets of $X$ such that $\cup S=X$. Let $B$ denote the collection of all sets that can be obtained by intersection a finite number of members of $S$. Finally, let $T$ denote the collection of all sets that can be obtained as the union of some subfamily of $B$.

Why $S\cap\emptyset=X$ and  $B\cup \emptyset = \emptyset$?

Somehow these statements are the other way around as in usual sets.

EDIT:
I attach a photo of the statements, perhaps I got confused with the phrasing in the book[image].

Comment: Hard to say. They look like either mistakes or non-standard definitions of binary $\cap$ and $\cup$.

Comment: They have the same standard theoretical meaning. These statements are in page 96 of Stromberg. _Introduction to Classical Real Analysis_. I think the claims are correct, but they are somehow cryptic due to the phrasing. I see if I can attach a photo that may dispel these doubts.

Comment: He's not making any such claim at all.  Why did you think he was?  He's saying (in parenthesis) that the intersection of emptysets is the emptyset and the union of emptysets is the emptyset (although why he is saying that I'm not sure).

Comment: Puff, what I feared..... just wrong phrasing(!)

Comment: Okay.  What he is claiming is $X$ is a finite intersection if you intersect *zero* sets, and that $\emptyset$ is a union if you union *zero* sets.

Comment: It is not $S\cap \emptyset=X$, it's "let $B$ denote the collection of all the subsets which can be obtained by intersecting a finite number of elements of $S$"  to which the author adds, between square brackets, the remark that he's using the convention $\cap\emptyset=X$. Likewise for your alleged $B\cup\emptyset=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miscopied it by omitting the square brackets: it actually just says that $\bigcap\varnothing=X$ and $\bigcup\varnothing=\varnothing$. The latter is clear: $\bigcup\varnothing$ is the set of things that are elements of some element of $\varnothing$, and since $\varnothing$ has no elements, this set must be empty. That $\bigcap\varnothing=X$ in this setting is a useful convention. If $\mathscr{A}$ is a collection of sets, how does some $x$ **fail** to belong to $\bigcap\mathscr{A}$? There must be some $A\in\mathscr{A}$ such that $x\notin A$. If $\mathscr{A}=\varnothing$, there can’t be any $A\in\mathscr{A}$ with $x\notin A$, so $x$ cannot fail to belong to the intersection. If we took this literally, $\bigcap\varnothing$ would have to contain every set, which is impossible, thanks to [Russell’s paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox), so in practice we simply set $\bigcap\varnothing$ equal to the set of ‘reasonable’ candidates for membership in such an intersection. In this case that’s the underlying set for the space.

Comment: Ok so $\cap \emptyset=X$ is just "vacously true", right?

Comment: @user2820579: Basically yes, but with the added restriction that we can’t let it include everything that vacuous truth would put into it, so we limit it to an appropriate ‘universe’.